# Takagi Sugeno system in R with frbs something wrong with rulebase

Tags: r, fuzzy-logic

I've been trying to use the R Statistical software to build a Takagi Sugeno fuzzy system. Using the R package `frbs` I've managed to set up the most of components of the FIS following the example in the demo files. Unfortunately, I've hit a problem:

> Error in rule[, (4 * i), drop = FALSE] : subscript out of bounds

in line:

```
res <- predict(object, newdata)$predicted.val
```

I have no idea what is wrong in this script. Rules should be good, the same I use in MATLAB script and it works. I do everything like it is in documentation and examples in `frbs` library.

```
#rm(list=ls())
library(frbs)
varinp.mf <- matrix(c( 5, -1, 0.8493, NA, NA, 5, 1, 0.8493, NA, NA,
                       5, -1, 0.8493, NA, NA, 5, 1, 0.8493, NA, NA),
                    nrow = 5, byrow = FALSE)
num.fvalinput <- matrix(c(2,2), nrow=1)
x1 <- c("a1","a2")
x2 <- c("b1","b2")
names.varinput <- c(x1, x2)
range.data <- matrix(c(-1.5,1.5, -1.5, 1.5, -1.5, 1.5), nrow=2)
type.defuz <- "5"
type.tnorm <- "MIN"
type.snorm <- "MAX"
type.implication.func <- "MIN"
name <- "Przykład"
newdata <- matrix(c(-0.6, 0.3), ncol = 2, byrow = TRUE)
colnames.var <- c("x1", "x2")
type.model <- "TSK"
func.tsk <- matrix(c(1,   1,  1,
                     2,   1,  0,
                     1,  -2, -1,
                     -1, 0.5, -2),
                   nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
# r1 <- c("a1","and","b1","->")
# r2 <- c("a1","and","b2", "->")
# r3 <- c("a2","and","b1", "->")
# r4 <- c("a2","and","b2", "->")
# rule <- list(r1,r2,r3,r4)
rule <- matrix(c("a1","and","b1","->",  
                 "a1","and","b2","->", 
                 "a2","and","b1","->",  
                 "a2","and","b2","->"),
              nrow = 4, byrow = TRUE)
object <- frbs.gen( range.data, num.fvalinput, names.varinput,
                    num.fvaloutput=NULL, varout.mf=NULL, names.varoutput=NULL, rule,
                    varinp.mf, type.model, type.defuz, type.tnorm, type.snorm,
                    func.tsk, colnames.var, type.implication.func)
plotMF(object)
res <- predict(object, newdata)$predicted.val
```

I see something is wrong in `object$rule` but i don't know how to fix it.

Answer (score 0):

According to documentation: *colnames.var
a list of names of input and output variables*. Just add the output like hat for example *colnames.var <- c("x1", "x2","o1")*.